# AccountChooser URL is randomly changed with Google OpenID Connect

Tags: google-oauth, openid-connect, google-openid

We are developing a web application with Google OpenID Connect Single Sign-On and currently having trouble in google authentication.

Every time we access the application login page, the URL of google account chooser is randomly changed.
Sometimes it goes to `https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=...` which is what we expects, sometimes goes to `https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?oauth=1&continue=...` that results in `400. That’s an error. The server cannot process the request because it is malformed. It should not be retried. That’s all we know.` shown in google error page.

We follow https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect to implement OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow.
Here are some of parameters we specified in auth request.

```
response_type: "code"
scope: "openid email"
openid.realm: App URL
redirect_uri: App callback URL
nonce: Not set
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.